# problem with figures

Tags: floats

[image]

Once I load a figure it is always in the right of the page and with that written how can I center it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{../Dropbox/TesiDellOlmo/Tesi scritto/immagini/prices.png} 
\end{center} `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be a space in the filepath. Try loading `\usepackage[space]{grffile}`
to avoid issues with spaces in files.

You should not use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` as it adds extra space around your figure. Just use `\centering` before `\includegraphics`